# Run VBS from Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, vbscript

I recently had a need to run VBScripts from SQL.  I figured rather than holding the scripts in  an external file I'd prefer to have them hosted in the DB where they're easier to maintain.  In order to do this the best method I could come up with was to create functionality to push these scripts to a temp file, run the temp file, then delete it.  I've included the script as a solution here, but would appreciate any feedback if you guys have other ideas also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code allows users to run scripts which are hosted inside the database.
The scripts are run on the host server, under the server's service account.  Temp script files are put in the service account's temp path (as defined by the environment variable %temp%).

```
use [DemoDatabase]
go
----use below code to enable commands (required for xp_cmdshell to work)
--exec sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
--go
--reconfigure
--go
--exec sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1  
--go
--reconfigure
--go

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

if OBJECT_ID('vbsScripts') is not null drop table vbsScripts
go
create table vbsScripts 
(
    id bigint not null identity(1,1) constraint pk_vbsScripts primary key clustered 
    , name nvarchar(256) not null constraint uk_vbsScripts_name unique
    , script nvarchar(max) not null
    , timeoutSecs int null constraint df_vbsScripts_timeoutSecs default(86400)--leave as null if you don't want a timeout / defaults to 1 day / 24*60*60
    , batchMode bit not null constraint df_vbsScripts_batchMode default(1)
)
go

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

/*
Gets the temp directory from environment variables
usage:
    declare @tempPath nvarchar(max)
    exec GetTempDirectory @tempPath out 
    select @tempPath 
*/
if OBJECT_ID('GetTempDirectory') is not null drop proc GetTempDirectory
go
create proc GetTempDirectory(@path nvarchar(max) out)
as
begin
    set @path = ''
    declare @tempTable table(data nvarchar(max))
    insert @tempTable exec master..xp_cmdshell 'echo %temp%'
    select top 1 @path = data from @tempTable
    if SUBSTRING(@path,len(@path),1) <> '\' set @path = @path + '\'
end
go

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/*
Creates a unique filename (using guid to ensure uniqueness and datetime to make the name friendlier)
usage:
    declare @tempPath nvarchar(max)
    exec GetTempDirectory @tempPath out 
    select @tempPath 
*/
if OBJECT_ID('GetTempFilename') is not null drop proc GetTempFilename
go
create proc GetTempFilename(@fn nvarchar(max) out)
as
begin
    --exec GetTempDirectory @fn out --can just use environment variable - originally had issues testing as was looking at the wrong user's temp directory :/
    --set @fn = @fn + 'sqlTemp_' + replace(replace(replace(convert(nvarchar(24), getutcdate(),127),'-',''),':',''),'.','') + '_' + CAST(NEWID() as nvarchar(36)) + '.tmp'
    set @fn = '%temp%\' + 'sqlTemp_' + replace(replace(replace(convert(nvarchar(24), getutcdate(),127),'-',''),':',''),'.','') + '_' + CAST(NEWID() as nvarchar(36)) + '.tmp'
end
go

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

if OBJECT_ID('dbo.fn_EscapeDosCharachters') is not null drop function dbo.fn_EscapeDosCharachters
go
create function dbo.fn_EscapeDosCharachters
(
    @text nvarchar(max)
)
returns nvarchar(max)
as
begin
    --http://www.dostips.com/?t=Snippets.Escape
    set @text = REPLACE(@text,'^','^^')
    set @text = REPLACE(@text,'!','^!')
    set @text = REPLACE(@text,'&','^&')
    set @text = REPLACE(@text,'|','^|')
    set @text = REPLACE(@text,'%','%%')
    return @text
end
go
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

if OBJECT_ID('createTempTextFile') is not null drop proc createTempTextFile
go
create proc createTempTextFile
(
    @fn nvarchar(max) out 
                      --the filename to output to (nb: environment variables don't currently work (e.g. you can't use %temp%\myFile.vbs)
                      --works fine with spaces in filename (so far at least)
                      --if user passes null a temporary filename will be auto allocated & returned in this variable
    , @content nvarchar(max)
)
as
begin

    declare @charPos int
    , @cmd varchar(8000) --has to be varchar rather than nvarchar due to xp_cmdshell implementation

    if @fn is null or LEN(@fn)=0
    begin
        exec GetTempFilename @fn out
    end

    set @cmd = '@echo.>' + @fn --create a new file for our script output
    EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd, no_output

    set @content = replace(@content,char(13) + char(10), char(10))--ensure uniform line endings (i.e. \r\n -> \n)
    set @content = replace(@content,char(13), char(10))--ensure uniform line endings (i.e. \r -> \n)
    set @content = @content + CHAR(10) --ensure last character of script is new line
    set @charPos = CHARINDEX(char(10),@content)
    while (@charPos > 0)
    begin
        --todo: consider what additional escaping is required to prevent injection issues
        set @cmd = '@echo.' + dbo.fn_EscapeDosCharachters(SUBSTRING(@content,1,@charPos-1)) + '>> ' + @fn
        EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd, no_output
        set @content = SUBSTRING(@content,@charPos+1,len(@content))
        set @charPos = CHARINDEX(char(10),@content)
    end

end 
go
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

if OBJECT_ID('deleteTempTextFile') is not null drop proc deleteTempTextFile
go
create proc deleteTempTextFile
(
    @fn nvarchar(max)
)
as
begin
    declare @cmd varchar(8000)
    if CHARINDEX(' ',@fn)>0 and CHARINDEX('"',@fn)>1 set @fn = QUOTENAME(@fn,'"')
    set @cmd = 'del ' + @fn
    EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd, no_output
end
go
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


if OBJECT_ID('sp_RunScript') is not null drop proc sp_RunScript
go
create proc sp_RunScript
(
    @scriptId bigint
    , @arguments nvarchar(max)
)
as
begin
    declare @timeoutSecs int
    , @batchMode bit
    , @script nvarchar(max)
    , @tempfileUri nvarchar(max)
    , @cmd varchar(8000) --has to be varchar rather than nvarchar due to xp_cmdshell implementation

    select @timeoutSecs=timeoutSecs 
    , @batchMode = batchMode
    , @script = script
    from vbsScripts 
    where id = @scriptId

    exec createTempTextFile @tempfileUri out, @script

    if CHARINDEX(' ',@tempfileUri)>0 and CHARINDEX('"',@tempfileUri)>1 set @tempfileUri = QUOTENAME(@tempfileUri,'"')
    set @cmd = 'cscript ' + @tempfileUri + ' //E:vbscript //NOLOGO '

    --batch mode or interactive
    if @batchMode=1 
        set @cmd = @cmd + '//B '
    else
        set @cmd = @cmd + '//I '

    --should script timeout after x seconds?
    if @timeoutSecs is not null
        set @cmd = @cmd + '//T:' + CAST(@timeoutSecs as nvarchar(18)) + ' '

    set @cmd = @cmd + isnull(@arguments,'')
    --select @cmd --if debugging enable this line to see the script file / etc

    EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd --if required we can capture output as has been done in GetTempDirectory

    exec deleteTempTextFile @tempfileUri --tidyup the temp script - disable this line for debugging

end
go
if OBJECT_ID('sp_RunScriptByName') is not null drop proc sp_RunScriptByName
go

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/*
provides a friendly interface to sp_RunScript
*/
create proc sp_RunScriptByName
(
    @scriptName nvarchar(256)
    , @arguments nvarchar(max)
)
as
begin

    declare @id bigint

    select @id = id
    from vbsScripts 
    where name = @scriptName

    exec sp_RunScript @id, @arguments

end
go

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--demo

--register a new script in the scripts table
insert vbsScripts 
select 'demo', '
option explicit
dim objFSO, i, path
path = "c:\example1\"
wscript.echo "hello" ''show what console output looks like (if interactive)
for i = 0 to wscript.Arguments.Count-1 ''show that we can handle command line arguments
    wscript.echo wscript.arguments.item(i)
next
set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")    
if not objFSO.FolderExists(path) then
    objFSO.CreateFolder(path) ''create a folder to demonstrate that the vbs is running / affecting the outside environment
else
    wscript.echo "Folder " & path & " already exists."
end if
set objFSO = Nothing
', null, 0
go

--execute above script via friendly name
sp_RunScriptByName 'demo','"this is a demo" "hopefully it will work" yes it does'
```

Comment: phew, not gonna read all that code, have something running like that in just a few lines, i'll post an example tomorrow